# How to create report in JasperServer using existing jrxml?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to create report from the existing jrxml using JasperServer.

I have created jrxml file through iReport.
I want to use an XML file as the datasource.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read the JasperServer documentation (tutorials)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure where you might be having trouble, but here are some basic instructions.

In iReport you can follow these instructions with the report open in design view.

1) In Repository Navigator right-click and select Add -> Report Unit

2) Enter the name and label for the new report.

3) Click the Get source from current opened report.

4) Select your data source.

You need to have a Jasper Server already set up in the Report Navigator.
You will also need to have a data source set up for the Jasper Server you are using.